# Is the POST string of an HTTP POST request always in plain text?

Tags: http, networking, unicode, post, encoding

as the title says:

speaking about HTTP requests: a GET is always in plain text.. i.e. GET www.myresource.com
but a POST request? I know that you can encode it with unicode but my question is this:
is encoded the part of the text after the string POST or also the string POST? is it always?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You may need to clarify, but I'll answer what I think you're asking.

GET and POST requests **can** be syntactically equivalent... consider

```
GET /myscript.php?param=val HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.com
```

versus

```
POST /myscript.php?param=val HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.com
```

The script, in fact, is called in exactly the same way. The difference is entirely semantic - `POST` requests are expected to "do something", while `GET`s are supposed to be safe always.

But, `POST` can also include a body. `GET` cannot - you can only pass what you fit in the URL. This allows file uploads, and so on, that a GET couldn't possibly do. Specifically, using the `multipart/form-data` encoding, you can send otherwise-unencoded binary data.

Is that what you were asking?

Comment: uhm yes.. so the POST is always in plain text.. can be encoded only the "data" of the POST, right?

Comment: The request itself should be plain text, perhaps encoded with Punycode: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode

Comment: uhm got it..  the test is from this website: http://www.snee.com/xml/crud/posttest.html